# How compare number with numbers inside myfile

Tags: c, file

I'm developing a software and i need to insert students and check if the same students are already registered in system.

```
int setNumAluno()       //Definir num de aluno
{
    int num;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Numero de Aluno: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("A verificar se existe o aluno\n");
    checkstudent(num);
    return num;



}

void checkstudent(int num)//Metodo responsavel por verrificar no ficheiro se o mesmo existe
{
    int numerofile=0;
    int r = 0;

    while (numerofile != EOF)
    {
        numerofile = fscanf(fp, "%d", &r);
        if (num == numerofile)
            printf("Numero existe");
        else if (num != numerofile)
            setNomeAluno();

    }

}
```

i've tryed implement an while cycle but i can't check if the number already exists in my file. The file is called when i do the `fscanf()` instruction but i can't check if already have a member with this number. How i can perform, my code, for verify if already a student exists or not?

Comment: Where do you open your file? How does your file look like?

Comment: stating the obvious, but I have to... to know that it doesn't exists you have to check *all* the entries.

Comment: i opened my file throught these instruction FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

Comment: filename is a const char that contain my path

Comment: If `numerofile = fscanf(fp, "%d", &r);` succeeds, `numerofile` will be `1` not the value you are reading, so using the function argument to test it with `if (num == numerofile)` is unlikely to do whatever is your intention. Use `if (num == r)`

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

1. Use `fopen` to open the file and create a `FILE` pointer.
2. Use `fread` to read the contents of the file into a buffer.
3. Use `strtol` to convert the numbers in the buffer into a `long int`; note that there are other functions for other other type conversions.
4. Use `fclose` to close the file and free the `FILE` pointer